# How to use ProgressDialog in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-asynctask, repeatingalarm

I'm having a serious problem when showing a ProgressDialog in a extend activity in BroadcastReceiver.
actually I want to get data in php file within every 5 second. I used AlarmManager to define time and 
used AsyncTask to get hosted php data.

this is my AlarmDemo Activity

```
public class AlarmDemo extends Activity {
Toast mToast;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_demo);

    // repeated alerm
    Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmDemo.this, RepeatingAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmDemo.this, 0,
            intent, 0);

    // We want the alarm to go off 5 seconds from now.
    long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    firstTime += 5 * 1000;

    // Schedule the alarm!
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, firstTime,
            5 * 1000, sender);

    // Tell the user about what we did.
    if (mToast != null) {
        mToast.cancel();
    }
    mToast = Toast.makeText(AlarmDemo.this, "Rescheduled",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    mToast.show();
    // end repeatdalarm

}
```

}

this is my RepeatingAlarm activity

```
public class RepeatingAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "availble now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

and this is my AsyncTask  Activity

```
public class AsyncronoustaskAndroidExample extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.asyncronoustask_android_example);



    String serverURL = "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/getPage.php";

    new LongOperation().execute(serverURL);


}

// Class with extends AsyncTask class
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private String Content;
    private String Error = null;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(
            AsyncronoustaskAndroidExample.this);
    TextView uiUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

        // UI Element
        uiUpdate.setText("Output : ");
        Dialog.setMessage("Downloading source..");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    // Call after onPreExecute method
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {



            // Server url call by GET method
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            Content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

        // Close progress dialog
        Dialog.dismiss();

        if (Error != null) {

            uiUpdate.setText("Output : " + Error);

        } else {

            uiUpdate.setText("Output : " + Content);

        }
    }

}
```

}

Now When I used AsyncTask and Alarm Manager code separately it is work find but when I try to combined those to in onReceive method, there is a error in ProgressDialog. it said that "The constructor ProgressDialog(RepeatingAlarm) is undefined". Can you please help me, because I'm new in Android

Comment: Don't tell us "there is an error".  Tell us what the error was.

Comment: @GabeSechan yes the error is  "The constructor ProgressDialog(RepeatingAlarm) is undefined"

Comment: A BroadcastReceiver is not a Context.  You can't pass it in where a Context is expected.  If you need a Context, you need to pass in the Context provided to you in onReceive.

Comment: You're trying to call a function that doesn't exist.  The function you're trying to call takes a Context as a parameter.  You're not passing it one, you're passing it a BroadcastReceiver.  Pass it the Context you're given in onReceive instead.

Comment: @GabeSechan I want just check the data in every 5 second. Is the Repeated Alarm suitable for it?

Comment: You want to check the progress of an AsyncTask?  No, not at all.  Instead you should have the AsyncTask publish its progress, that functionality is built into the AsyncTask class and you just need to implement it.

Comment: I removed Context in on onReceive but it did not work for me.

Comment: That's not what I said to do.  I think you need to step back from trying to fix this problem and think about how functions work and why doing that was silly.

Comment: @GabeSechan Can you please propose a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

    Toast.makeText(context, "available now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```